# How to create multiple views by looping in UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I want to create multiple textfields.
Instead of doing

```
let textfield1 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield2 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield3 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield4 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield5 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield6 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield7 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield8 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield9 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield10 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield11 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield12 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield13 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield14 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield15 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield16 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield17 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield18 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield19 = SecondTextfieldView()
let textfield20 = SecondTextfieldView()
```

I want to loop it -- make it short and sweet. How can I do it in UIkit (Swift)?
***** NOT IN SWIFTUI *****

Comment: why you are tried with tableview with the help of tag

Answer (score 4):

try this code:

create stack view for adding all multiple views

```
let stackView = UIStackView.init()
        stackView.spacing = 2
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        self.view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
```

create loop for create subView like this:

```
for i in 0 ... 9 { // create 10 UIView
        let view = UIView.init()
        view.backgroundColor = colors[i] // sample color for see diffrence
        
        // insert to stackView or etc for showing
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
    }
```

create array color for assign to subView:

```
var colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .black ,.blue,.green, .yellow, .brown, .red, .blue, .yellow, .brown]
```

**output**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code I've used in a previous project:

```
    private enum Feature: String {
    case intro
    case account

    var selector: Selector {
        switch self {
        case .intro: return #selector(navigateToIntro)
        case .account: return #selector(navigateToAccount)
        }
    }
}

override func loadView() {
    let views = createButtons(for: .intro, .account)
    view = createStackView(with: views)
}

private func createButtons(for features: Feature...) -> [UIView] {
    features.map {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 10))
        button.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle($0.rawValue.capitalized, for: .normal)
        button.accessibilityIdentifier = $0.rawValue
        button.addTarget(self, action: $0.selector, for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }
}

private func createStackView(with subViews: [UIView]) -> UIStackView {
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: subViews)
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 10
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return stackView
}
```

It's designed so you can put items in the enum at the top and iterate through them all in loadView(), but you can set them up using viewDidLoad() too.